Add User Membership Plan as body class in WooCommerce
I need to add as body class the user Membership ID in WooCommerce.
For that, I use the following code:
add_filter( 'body_class', 'am_add_slug_body_class' );

function am_add_slug_body_class( $classes ) {
    global $post;
    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }
    return $classes;
}

/* Add Logged-Out Body Class */

add_filter('body_class','am_logged_in_filter');

function am_logged_in_filter($classes) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $classes[] = '';
    } else {
        $classes[] = 'logged-out';
    }
    return $classes;
}

/* Add Gold Membership to Body Class */

add_filter('body_class','am_membership_class_filter');

function am_membership_class_filter($classes) {
    if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 'prime' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'prime';
    }
    
    return $classes;

if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 'platinum' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'platinum';
    }
    return $classes;

if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, 'pro' ) ) {
        $classes[] = 'pro';
    }
    return $classes;

}

But it only works with the first Membership Plan "prime" (Premium), as Platinum and Pro plans don't work.
Is there any problem in this code? Why is my code not working properly?

Yes, it does look like you need to remove the first two return $classes; lines from am_membership_class_filter, if you want more than the first 4 lines to be reached.

In your last function, you are using return $classes; after the first IF statement, so the other IF statements get never read. When using a filter hook, the main filtered argument (here $classes) need to always be returned at the end.
Also, as you are using the same hook for your 3 functions, so instead, you can merge everything in a unique function (see below).
Try the following instead (replaces all your provided code):
add_filter('body_class','add_custom_body_class');
function add_custom_body_class($classes) {
    global $post;

    if ( isset( $post ) ) {
        $classes[] = $post->post_type . '-' . $post->post_name;
    }

    if( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $classes[] = 'logged-out';
    }

    $memberships = array('prime', 'platinum', 'pro'); 

    // Loop through each membership plan slug
    foreach( $memberships as $membership ) {
        if( wc_memberships_is_user_member( null, $membership ) ) {
            $classes[] = $membership;
        }
    }

    return $classes;
}

It should work now.
